# How do I produce a plot, using Gnuplot, where column 1 for each row is used as the key?

Tags: gnuplot

I currently have:

```
set terminal png
set datafile separator ","
set style data linespoints
set key
plot 'data/forplotting/population.csv' using 3:4 title column(1)
```

With the data file (not all of it... I don't want to flood this question):

```
Country Name,Country Code,Year,Value
Arab World,ARB,1960,96388069
Euro area,EMU,1960,260300607
Euro area,EMU,1961,262639170
Euro area,EMU,1962,265056064
Euro area,EMU,1963,267532538
Euro area,EMU,1964,269969434
Euro area,EMU,1965,272389008
Euro area,EMU,1966,274649191
Euro area,EMU,1967,276601113
Euro area,EMU,1968,278434336
Euro area,EMU,1969,280295897
Euro area,EMU,1970,281804083
Euro area,EMU,1971,283295830
```

and etc for all other countries.

I would like the output to be similar to

[image: desired outcome]

but I took a look at the source of the data used in this graph and it is not structured like mine.

My current output:

[image: current outcome]

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: The best option would be to convert your format to the one used by immigration.dat

Comment: @Christoph Yeah, but I wanted to know if there was another way...

Comment: I know, but no, there is no other way because you cannot use the content of a column as key entry. Because that would require gnuplot to internally group the rows based on the first column to generate a separate plot for each unique value of the first column. And this is not possible. If you don't  want to alter the original files you could use some external script written in any language you want (e.g. awk, python, etc) to do the conversion on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can plot such data with *gnuplot-only*.
You need to create a list of unique key entries and then filter your data accordingly (there are a few similar questions here).
The unique list of the countries is in the order of first occurrence.
Assumption is that the years are in chronological order. Unfortunately, gnuplot has no easy direct sorting capability (i.e. you have to go via external tools).

**Data:** `SO28874305.dat`

```
Country Name,Country Code,Year,Value
Austria, AT, 1960, 1
Austria, AT, 1970, 4
Austria, AT, 1980, 3
Austria, AT, 1990, 4
Austria, AT, 1995, 5
Belgium, BE, 1960, 3
Belgium, BE, 1965, 7
Belgium, BE, 1975, 5
Belgium, BE, 1980, 3
Denmark, DK, 1963, 6
Denmark, DK, 1967, 4
Denmark, DK, 1974, 2
Denmark, DK, 1988, 5
France,  FR, 1977, 2
France,  FR, 1989, 4
France,  FR, 1992, 3
France,  FR, 1997, 5
Germany, DE, 1972, 5
Germany, DE, 1980, 6
Germany, DE, 1983, 8
Germany, DE, 1995, 3
Germany, DE, 1999, 6
```

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012 and gnuplot 5.4.0, June 2020)

```
### use a column as legend
reset

FILE = "SO28874305.dat"
set datafile separator ","

# create a unique list of strings from a column
addToList(list,col) = list.( strstrt(list,' '.strcol(col)) > 0 ? '' : ' '.strcol(col))
Uniques=''
stats FILE u (Uniques=addToList(Uniques,1)) every ::1 nooutput
set datafile missing "NaN"

myFilter(colD,colF,valF) = (strcol(colF) eq valF) ? column(colD) : NaN

plot for [Country in Uniques] FILE u 3:(myFilter(4,1,Country)) w lp pt 7 ti Country
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) Sadly I can't remember what I was needing the graph for :D I assume for homework at highschool. Accepted, thanks for answering such an old question, will be useful for me in the future regardless as I still find gnuplot tricky. Do you have any recommendations of gnuplot books (free or otherwise)?

Comment: @Xack You're welcome! Actually, I didn't expect any response :-). If I see old unanswered questions which appear to me an interesting plotting case with realistic input data format, but people say it can't be done with gnuplot only, I feel encouraged to find a gnuplot-only solution. Sometimes it is rather easy, sometimes might get lengthy and complicated. I was learning gnuplot by doing, however, this takes time. I haven't used any book, but check the links on the gnuplot homepage: http://gnuplot.info/ StackOverflow is a good (interactive) source if you have a concrete problem.